# Event handler for odd and even elements

Tags: mootools

I have a bunch of span elements with css class option

```
<div>
<span class="option">
</div>
<div>
<span class="option">
</div>
<div>
<span class="option">
</div>
<div>
<span class="option">
</div>
```

I would like to select all of them, and then attach event handler to their mouseover event.I ended up with this:

```
 $$('.option').addEvents({
      'mouseover': function() {
            // code

       },

});
```

But I don't know how to figure out inside event handler, if current selected element is even or odd, so I can do different thing based on that information.

Comment: first off your span should not close with `</div>` and why not use a conditional with the indexOf `.option` and then use modulo like so if `num % 2 === 0` then its even else its odd..

Comment: no need. use a .each and the supplied iterator index in the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `each` to iterate over the options. This will give you the current index:

```js
$$('.option').each(function(elem, i) {
    elem.addEvents({
        mouseover: function() {
            if (i % 2) {
                // odd
            }
            else {
                // even
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can order your elements in different layout and then use mootools slick even,odd selections:

http://jsfiddle.net/49zpm/1/

```
$$('.option:even').addEvents({
    'mouseover': function () {
        console.log('mouseover even');
    }

});


$$('.option:odd').addEvents({
    'mouseover': function () {
        console.log('mouseover odd');
    }

});
```